# How to copy data in a file into a directory OR copy the command output into directory

Tags: unix, sed, awk

How to copy the output of this command into the other directory folder  ?

```
cd folder2
cp `ls | sort -k1.5 | head -8` /folder1/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xargs` to run `cp` for each item returned by your filter:

```
cd folder2
ls | sort -k1.5 | head -8 | xargs -I % cp % /folder1
```

Comment: Sorry, It's Done, I didnt add spances before and after cp so I was getting that error, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if *parallel* is installed :

```
ls | sort -k1.5 | head -8 |  parallel cp {} /folder1
```

*parallel* is so powerful , it can do much more complex things as [shown here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__working_as_xargs__n1__argument_appending) +

Answer (score 0):

The three descriptors connected in terminal .This are 0 is standard input and  1 is standard output and  2 is standard error

so the commands taken and use of this 3 descriptors

like ls command output is

Birthday_details2013.ods  Books.2/  IPC_with_sockets _power point_ppt_presentation_files/       untitled folder/

This output is placed on that stdout

The stdout is redirected to another file

```
home> ls 1>~/Desktop/file
```

for example

```
  ls | wc -c | wc -l  1>file
```

cat file

1

The another folder desktop contains the  file and that file stored the ls command output